# return value syntax and template not working

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is this code failing with

> error C2893: Failed to specialize function template ''unknown-type'
>   makeAndProcessObject(const Builder &)'

I'm using MSVC2012

```
class BBuilder
{
public:
    int makeObject()
    {
        return 22;
    }
};

template <typename Builder>
auto
makeAndProcessObject (const Builder& builder) -> decltype( builder.makeObject() )
{
    auto val = builder.makeObject();
    // do stuff with val
    return val;
}

int main()
{
    BBuilder myobj;
    auto retval = makeAndProcessObject(myobj);

    return 0;
}
```

(Live [example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1zimN5%242))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You function `makeObject` should be const, since you are trying to call this function on `constant object`, and then all works. [example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1zimN5$3)

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that

```
makeAndProcessObject (const Builder& builder) receives a const builder
```

but makeObject() function is not const !! so it cannot deduce the return ...
you can either remove the const qualifier or make makeObject const so it can find the function:

```
int makeObject() const
{
    return 22;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

since makeAndProcessObject function is taking constant reference object So it cannot access non constant member function(builder.makeObject()). Either convert makeObject() to constant member function[Ex :int makeObject() const]   or use non constant object in builder.makeObject() template function [ex: makeAndProcessObject (Builder& builder)]

Regards,
shivakumar